# How to create a binding in code and make a notification from property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

A View contains a couple of buttons.
In a ViewModel "IsShiftLock" property resides and a binding created dynamically.

```
 public bool IsShiftLock {
        get { return _isShiftLock; }
        set {
            if (value != _isShiftLock) {
                _isShiftLock = value;
                Notify("IsShiftLock");                   
            }
        }
    }
```

Notify is a method in a BaseViewModel.

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public void Notify(string sPropertyName)
{
  PropertyChangedEventHandler changedEventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
  if (changedEventHandler == null)
    return;
  changedEventHandler((object) this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(sPropertyName));
}
```

}

```
       Binding b2 = new Binding {
                    Source = this,
                    Path = new PropertyPath("IsShiftLock"),
                    Converter = new ShiftLockToTextConverter()
                };
                b2.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
                curKeyView.Button.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, b2);
```

IsShiftLock changes properly, but converter invokation occurs only once.
As I understand, binding should be properly notified of changes. How to accomplish that?

***update 1:***

View side:

```
private readonly KeyboardViewModel viewModel;
public static KeyboardViewModel ViewModelInstance;

    public VirtualKeyboard() {             
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new KeyboardViewModel();
            DataContext = viewModel;

            ViewModelInstance = viewModel;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some `xaml`? It might help.

Comment: The snippet of Binding - where is it residing: in the view or the view model? Also, `curKeyView.Button` - is `curKeyView` your view? If so, do you have a button there with the name of `Button`?

Comment: There is no xaml. I create xaml dynamically. Binding resides in a ViewModel. No, curKeyView is not a View. KeyView is a class which represents buttons and theirs types (no matter what it means).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that KeyViewModel itself inherited BaseViewModel and was subscribed for PropertyChangedEvent. I don't understand the whole picture, but I fixed the issue.

Each KeyViewModel was explicitly subscribed for PropertyChangedEvent, because of that, somehow, the bindings that I tried to set dynamically for Shift button and Caps Lock were knocked down or something. For unfortune I don't understand the overall picture under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in bindings `Source` property. You should set it to either `this.DataContext` or some other source and it will work.

```
            Binding b2 = new Binding {
                Source = this.DataContext,
                Path = new PropertyPath("IsShiftLock"),
                Converter = new ShiftLockToTextConverter()
            };
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. I need from a ViewModel put a ViewModel instance (which I instantiate in View) into Source. So, I did this: I created public static KeyboardViewModel ViewModelInstance in a View and now Source = VirtualKeyboard.ViewModelInstance. But it still doesn't work :( See, my update 1.

Comment: As I understand the problem now is a Notification. IsShiftLock invokes Notify, but how a binding should be subscribed for that? Am I right that a binding should be notified somehow about changes in properties?)))

Comment: When I debug I see that nobody is subscibed when Notify("IsShiftLock") being invoked.

Comment: @EngineerSpock Please add `xaml`. I've made sample solution and it's working for me.